# Why is accessing a non static method from static method is Bad design

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods, non-static

I am accessing non static method from static Method. Below is the code. I read its bad design [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13331502/8251821). Why this bad design please help me to understand.
If so how can one achieve it.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class Base 
{
public :
    static Base* initialiser;
    void BaseMethod() 
    {
        std::cout<<"Non static method Invoked"<<std::endl;
    }

    static  Base* GetInstance() 
    {
        if (!initialiser)
            initialiser = new Base();

        return initialiser;
    }
};

Base* Base::initialiser = nullptr;

class Service 
{
public: 
    void ServiceMethod()
    {
        Base::GetInstance()->BaseMethod();
    }
};

int main()
{
     Service obj;
     obj.ServiceMethod();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. In any case most most design questions are either matters of opinion or dependent on circumstances.

Comment: Singletons and global state in general is arguably bad design. Calling a non-static member function from a static one is a minute cosmetic detail, not a design issue at all.

Comment: Your `GetInstance` method should use a function level static variable to store and initialise the singleton, this is simpler, less code and safer

Comment: Is there even a reason to use a singleton in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is accessing a non static method from static method is Bad design

It is not per se, as you are actually using a static member from a static methods

Yet this code snipped is too damn rigid, too damn over-engineered. Which means more likely to be buggy, to be a mess once a new requirement come into play.

- defect : This code isn't thread safe. You should instantiate `initializer` not in `GetInstance`,rather using `Base* Base::initialiser{new Base()};`, which is guaranteed to be thread-safe from c++11.
- defect : A class such like this should be derived with extreme caution. Or add `final` to prevent this possibility.
- design : This code has still zero line of functionality. You are still plumbing. You want to reconsider if this is the best design for the problem being solved.
- design : The purpose is to provide a singleton. We dev like to enforce unnecessary constraints such as uniqueness. When the time comes to support two instances in a system designed for a singleton, we have to refactor a whole lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was for a general case, here is a quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods):

> Static methods are meant to be relevant to all the instances of a class rather than to any specific instance.
>
> A static method can be invoked even if no instances of the class exist yet.

Thus, you should consider static methods to be in class namespace meant for operations on a class rather than on instances/objects of the class.

In your case of making singleton, your are not accessing non-static method from a static one, but you are initializing an instance of that (static) object `initialiser` within the static method.